# Rails 3.1 form_for missing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working with a model that I know is working (records exist in the data base, can be searched for and displayed in other views, etc.) but when I try to use the form_for tag to generate a view for editing one of these records, I get an error message:

Showing `/var/www/caucus/app/views/registration_loader/checkIn.html.erb` where line #13 raised:

```
undefined method `voter_path' for #<#<Class:0x98cabdc>:0x98c8878>
```

Extracted source (around line #13):

```
10: </div>
11: 
12: <%= form_for(
13:     @voter,
14:     { :controller => "registration_loader",
15:       :action     => "editVoter"
16:     } ) do |f| %>
```

The `@voter` refers to a Voter object retrieved by:

```
#   Get the voter.
@voter = Voter.where( [ "voter_id = ?", @voterId ] )[ 0 ]
if not @voter
    flash[ :error ] = "NO VOTER!"
    redirect_to :action => 'search'
elsif not @voter.kind_of?( Voter )
    flash[ :error ] = "NO VOTER RECORD! (#{@voter.class.to_s})"
    redirect_to :action => 'search'
end
```

When I change the `@voter` to `:voter`, it stops giving me the error, but does not populate the fields in my view with the data for the record I want to edit.

According to the Rails 3.1 API guide, passing a model object into `form_for` should generate code that allows me to edit the data in that object, but evidently there is a missing helper method (`voter_path`). Where is this `voter_path` method supposed to be defined, and what is its proper semantic and signature? Nowhere in the documentation is creating such a method discussed, nor can I find any examples of writing such a method.

Is the `*_path` method supposed to be auto-generated?  If not, can someone point me to the documentation that specifies the syntax and semantics of this method?

Thanks,
John S.

Comment: What's your `routes.rb` file look like? Do you have a resource in there for your voter objects?

Comment: Thanks for answering!  (Darn it, this interface surprised me!)  Your reply suggests that the URL I build using :controller and :action is incorrect in some way.  I do have a route for that URL: registration_loader_editVoter POST /registration_loader/editVoter(.:format) {:controller=>"registration_loader", :action=>"editVoter"}.  Does form_for not default to post?

Comment: Adding resources :voters worked partially, but I can't understand why, as there is no voter(s) controller.  What does Rails 3.1 do with a route to a non-existent controller?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't use form_for unless you have also designed your code to use "resourceful controllers".  Use form_tag instead.  Adding resources :voters to routes creates routes to a non-existent controller.